# Characterizing a surface in $R^3$ with a given metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, isometric-immersion

Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How can I find a surface in $R^3$ such that their curvature are the same? The shape of the surface in $3$ space is important. I mean I dont like to equip for example the sphere with the metric $g$. Since, I see it as a sphere and its curvature is $1$ every where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nash embedding theorem for 2D manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37708/nash-embedding-theorem-for-2d-manifolds)