# Isometric embedding of a genus g surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, metric-embeddings

Can a genus $g$ surface with constant negative curvature and $g>1$ be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4?$

Comment: Is there any example or counter example?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528046/can-a-hyperbolic-surface-be-isometrically-embedded-into-mathbb-r4

Comment: So, is this an open problem?

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/37708/21564) and its answers.

Answer (score 11):

The [Nash-Kuiper Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) implies the answer is yes if you only require the embedding to be of class $C^1$.  However, I believe the actual visualization problem for $g\geq 2$ (that is, producing the embedding in this case) is an open problem (unlike the visualization of the $C^1$-embedding of the [flat torus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYH_KXhF1SY), which has a $C^\infty$-isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^4$).

Since the [smallest known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528046/can-a-hyperbolic-surface-be-isometrically-embedded-into-mathbb-r4) $C^\infty$-embedding for the hyperbolic plane is $\mathbb{R}^6$ I would guess the answer is no for a genus 2 hyperbolic surface (but as far as I know it is open).  Note it is a theorem of Hilbert that the hyperbolic plane cannot be $C^r$-embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ for $r\geq 2$.  Later Efimov generalized this to closed hyperbolic surfaces.

I believe these facts and references may be found in:

*Isometric Embedding of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces* by Qing Han, and Jia-Xing Hong.

Comment: There are visualizations of the Nash--Kuiper embeddings here: http://hevea-project.fr/

Comment: @JohnPardon Thanks for the link. However, I already knew about the flat tori and Nash spheres from Hevea; I referenced one in my answer.  It is the hyperbolic ones for closed surfaces of $g\geq 2$ that are not presently visualized (as far as I know).

Comment: That's a confusing place to put the link: the smooth flat embedding of the torus in R^4 and the C^1 flat embedding of the torus in R^3 aren't related at all.

Comment: @JohnPardon I was trying to contrast the situation for $g=1$ and $g\geq 2$ (minimal smooth embedding vs visualization of $C^1$-embedding).  Sorry if it confused you.  I made an edit that hopefully makes my intent more clear.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: There isn't really any difference between the $g=1$ and $g\geq 2$ cases for the Nash--Kuiper construction of C^1 isometric embeddings; their method works for an arbitrary metric without regard to its curvature.  I'm fairly certain that if one can render a flat torus in R^3, then one can render any surface with any metric in R^3, though the people at Hévéa might know better. (+1 btw)

Comment: @JohnPardon Sure, I know the method works theoretically in general, but actually doing it is computationally complicated (which is why it hasn't been done).

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the answer to your question, and I wouldn't be surprised if it were open. You may be interested to know that any compact Riemannian two-manifold $(V, g)$ admits a $C^{\infty}$ isometric embedding $V \to \mathbb{R}^5$. See Gromov's *Partial Differential Relations*, pages 298 - 303.