# Areas dominated by two points on a surface: Equal?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $S$ be a smooth compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with two distinct, distinguished points
$a,b \in S$.  Let $R(a)$ be all the points of $S$ closer to $a$ than to $b$, and $R(b)$ all the
points of $S$ closer to $b$ than to $a$, where distance is measured by shortest paths on the surface.
The points equally distant from $a$ and $b$ form a *bisector*, a closed curve on $S$.
This is in a sense the Voronoi diagram of the two points on $S$.

---

> **Q1**. Is the area of $R(a)$ equal to the area of $R(b)$?  Suppose $S$ has genus zero,
>   or is even convex—Do these restrictions change the answer?

**Answer:** Jack Huizenga's examples in his comment show the answer is a strong `No`, even for a convex surface.

> **Q2**. Following Vitali Kapovitch's comment suggestion, is the sphere the only closed, bounded, genus-zero surface for
>   which $R(a)=R(b)$ for every pair $a,b$?

---

**Addendum**.
There is no need for $S$ to be smooth, and indeed I am primarily interested in polyhedra,
specifically, convex polyhedra. I am now thinking it is an interesting question to identify
all the pairs of points $(x,y)$ for which their bisector $B=B(x,y)$ halves the surface area,
e.g.:

           
[image: Box bisector]

But I should save that for perhaps a separate question...

Comment: Join two spheres by a small cylinder, where one of the spheres is much larger than the other.  Take $a$ to be on the cylinder, and $b$ to be on the smaller sphere, away from the cylinder.  Clearly $R(a)$ is much larger than $R(b)$.

Simply taking the surface to be a very long narrow cylinder (smoothed out accordingly) and picking $a$ and $b$ appropriately, one can rig convex examples.

Comment: @Jack: Ah, I see, very nice example--Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that pretty much the opposite should be true. that is if the areas are equal for any $a$ and $b$ then S should have constant curvature.

Comment: Indeed, Jack's example suggests another natural class if we start with a cone and place b at the apex and a not too far from b.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.17

Comment: For question 2, I nominate without proof the torus.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.01.18

Comment: @Gerhard: Ah yes, I should have qualified Q2 with *genus zero*. Point well-taken!

Comment: Aren't Vital's and Gerhard's comments contradictory to one another?  If I'm not mistaken, a torus cannot have constant (flat) curvature when embedded in R^3 and given the induced metric.

Comment: @Gerard: Added *genus-zero* to Q2.
@Jack: Good point! Although if we leave the smooth category, matters change.  See the MO question, "$C^1$ isometric embedding of flat torus into $\mathbb{R}^3$: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31222/