# embeddings of product of spheres in Euclidean spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces, embeddings

I notice that $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a hypersurface (submnaifolds of codimension 1).

In general,

(1). could the product of spheres $S^{m_1}\times\cdots\times S^{m_n}$ be embedded in Euclidean space as a hypersurface?

(2). could  $T^n=\prod_n S^{1}$ be embedded in Euclidean space as a hypersurface?

(3). could $S^m\times S^n$ be embedded in Euclidean space as a hypersurface?

Comment: You've asked 55 questions on MO so far (72 if I count your other two accounts that I know of, and 86 if I count math.SE), but answered 0 (everywhere). The SE system doesn't work unless people also answer questions in addition to asking them. Please consider answering some questions in the future and giving back to the community.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be closed?  This is a homework-type question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes. Once I meet a question that I have a solution, I will answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [asked on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/product-of-spheres-embeds-in-euclidean-space-of-1-dimension-higher), and answered (see [Jim Belk's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/161313), which is **NOT** the accepted answer).

Comment: What about the minimum dimension at which the embedding can be made isometric?

Comment: If the category is $C^1,$ then the same dimension as the topological embedding dimension :)

Comment: This is really cool; I didn't know $\mathcal{C}^1$ is so powerful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31222/c1-isometric-embedding-of-flat-torus-into-mathbbr3