# Is there a $W^{2,2}$ isometric embedding of the flat torus into $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, regularity, isometric-immersion

It is well known that [there exists a  $C^1$ isometric embedding of flat torus into $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31222/c1-isometric-embedding-of-flat-torus-into-mathbbr3), and that this embedding cannot be $C^2$.

Is there a $W^{2,2}$ isometric embedding? (i.e an isometric map $f \in W^{2,2}(\mathbb{T}^2,\mathbb{R}^3)$?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an expansion on my comment to @j.c. 's answer.

We want to use Pakzad's result cited in that answer in order to prove that there is no $f$ as in the original question.

My idea:
By Sobolev embedding theorems we have that $f\in C^{0,\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in (0,1)$.  In particular, the image $\Sigma=f(\mathbb{T}^2)$ is a compact set.  As such, there is an $R_0>0$ so that 
$$\Sigma\subset B_{R_0}(0)$$
where here $B_{R_0}(0)$ is the open euclidean ball of radius $r_0$ centered at the origin.
Now let 
$$
R=\inf\{ \rho>0: \Sigma \subset B_\rho(0)\}
$$
and observe that, as $\Sigma$ is compact $\Sigma\cap \partial B_{R}\neq \emptyset$.  In particular, there is a $p'\in \Sigma\cap \partial B_{R}$ and so, there is a $p\in \mathbb{T}^2$ so $f(p)=p'$.

Now pick a small radius $r$ so that $\exp_p: B_r(0)\to \mathbb{T}^2$ is an isometry onto it's image (here we use that the metric on the torus is flat) and consider the map $\tilde{f}=f\circ \exp_p|_{B_r(0)}$.  Observe, that $\tilde{f}(0)=p'$.  By Pakzad's result, up to shrinking $r$ we know that either $\tilde{f}$ is affine or there is a line through $0$ on which $\tilde{f}$ is affine.  As $f$ is isometric these affine functions are non-constant and so the image of $\tilde{f}$ contains a line segment through $p'$. This segment must leave $\bar{B}_R(0)$ which contradicts the choice of $R$.

Answer (score 13):

It is a result of Pakzad's that $W^{2,2}$ isometric immersions $f$ of bounded regular convex domains with Lipschitz boundary $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ must be developable; more precisely, for every point $x$ of $f(\Omega)$, $f$ must restrict to an affine function on either (1) a neighborhood of $x$ or (2) a line segment passing through $x$ connecting two points of $\partial\Omega$.

This should "rule" out an isometric embedding of $\mathbb{T}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (forgive the pun).

See Theorem II of:

*Pakzad, Mohammad Reza*, [**On the Sobolev space of isometric immersions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1090415029), J. Differ. Geom. 66, No. 1, 47-69 (2004). [ZBL1064.58009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1064.58009).

What's still missing is a classification of developable surfaces in the $W^{2,2}$ setting; I suspect it should be the same as the classical one but I should think some more...

**edit 2**: In fact, such a classification is not necessary to show that there is no $W^{2,2}$ immersion of a flat torus into $\mathbb{R}^3$. See RBega's answer for a much nicer proof of that fact than what follows here!

**edit**: The following was inspired by RBega's comment below before I fully understood it. Hopefully this works:

Suppose there is a point $p$ of type (2). Let $\Omega$ be $\mathbb{T}^2$ minus an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the cut locus at $p$, thought of as a domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $\mathbb{T}^2$ minus its cut locus looks like the Voronoi cell of $p$ in the universal cover so $\Omega$ satisfies the assumptions in Pakzad's theorem. Then by Pakzad's theorem, the line segment through $f(p)$ connects the images of two points $p_1,p_2$ on $\partial\Omega$. Let $r=d_{\mathbb{T}^2}(p_1,p_2)$ and $R=d_{\mathbb{R}^3}(f(p_1),f(p_2))$, so that $f(p)$ lies on a straight line segment $l\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ of length $R$ between $f(p_1),f(p_2)$. For $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, I claim that $R>r$ which leads to a contradiction. Explicitly, $l$ is a minimizer of distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so $R$ is a lower bound for the distance between $f(p_1)$ and $f(p_2)$ in $f$, so the true distance $r$ cannot be achieved by $f$.

I don't have a particularly clean proof of $R>r$ for all flat tori but I think that this will follow from some case analysis on the possible Voronoi cells of lattices in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, consider the square flat torus of area $a^2$. We can take $\Omega$ to be a square with side length $a-\epsilon$, with $p$ at its center. Then among the pairs of points $(p_1,p_2)$ on $\partial\Omega$ that lie on some geodesic through $p$, the maximal distance $r$ between $p_1$ and $p_2$ is less than $a/2$, while the minimum length $R$ of a geodesic joining $p_1$ and $p_2$ through $p$ is at least $a-2\epsilon$.

Finally, if there can be no points of type (2), then we are left with only points of type (1), but that implies that $f$ itself is affine, which leads to a contradiction as well.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please say why the image of the flat Torus under a $W^{2,2}$ isometric map cannot be developable? (i.e I don't see why the theorem you mentioned imply there is no such embedding).

Comment: @AsafShachar You're right that there's a missing argument. I was hoping that the classification of developable surfaces (see e.g. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160140333/full ) would easily extend to this setting but I don't see it immediately. I'll edit.

Comment: Wouldn't the following argument work given the result of Pakzad?  Pick the infimum of radii $r$ so that $f(\mathbb{T}^2)\subset B_{r}$ (here $B_r$ is the euclidean ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$).  This means that there is a $p\in \mathbb{T}^2$ so that $f(p)\in B_{r}$, but any line segment through $f(p)$ lying in the sphere would have to leave the ball giving a contradiction.

Comment: @Rbega Perhaps this is trivial, but how do you know the image $f(\mathbb{T}^2)$ is bounded?

Comment: @AsafShachar The image $f(\mathbb{T}^2)$ must be bounded, otherwise we can find pairs of points whose distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is arbitrarily large. Distances in the image are bounded below by distances in $\mathbb{R}^3$,  and this contradicts the facts that $\mathbb{T}^2$ has a finite metric diameter and that $f$ preserves distances.

Comment: @Rbega thanks for the comment! I think your argument relied on my former description of Pakzad's theorem which skipped some details (now added). However, you did inspire my attempt in my newest edit. Let me know if you see a simpler proof.

Comment: @AsafShachar Shouldn't it follow from the Rellich embedding theorem to see that $f\in W^{1,q}(\mathbb{T}^2)$ for any $q<\infty$ (there is probably a finer result here but its not needed) and then you can use embedding of Sobolev spaces in Holder spaces to see $f\in C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{T}^2)$ for any $\alpha<1$.

Comment: Ah, maybe I misunderstood the sense of "bounded" in Asaf Shachar's comment...

Comment: @j.c. Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but can't you just find the extreme point $p$ from my earlier comment, then take a small geodesic ball (in $\mathbb{T}^2$) about $p$ (small enough to be developed to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with convex boundary) and then apply the Pakzad's result to the restriction (which will still give a contradiction).

Comment: @Rbega I think it may be me that is missing something. Would you mind writing up a separate answer for your argument with some more details? In particular I guess I do not understand how precisely you are choosing $p$ in the earlier comment and in what sense it is extreme.