# Names of certain surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, surfaces, calculus-of-variations

Are there any generally used names for the following algebraic and nonalgebraic surfaces? Any references to literature where the surfaces are studied are also appreciated.

Surface I. Implicit equation: $z^2(z^2-16x)=64y^2$. Parametric form: $\mathbf{r}(u,v)=\left(
u^2-v^2,
2 u v ,
4 u 
\right)$ 
It is a graph of a harmonic function $z(x,y)=\pm 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.822477a25b.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.822477a25b.png)

Surface II. Implicit equation:
$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) z^4 - 2 (8 x^2 + 9 y^2 + 9 z^2) x z^2 - 27 (y^2 + z^2)^2=0$
Parametric form: $\mathbf{r}(u,v)=\frac{1}{1+u^2+v^2}\left(
u^4-3 u^2v^2-3u^2,  4 u^3 v, 4 u^3 \right)$

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.9ac2e93b82.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.9ac2e93b82.png)

Surface III. Implicit equation:
$z^2(y^2+z^2)\left(z^2-4y-4\right)^2 +
  x^2 \left(64 y^3 - 24 (y-3) y z^2 - 6 (y+6) z^4 + z^6\right)-27 x^4 z^2 =0$
Parametric form:
$\mathbf{r}(u,v)=\frac{1}{1+u^2+v^2}\left(
2 uv(u^2-v^2-1),  u^2 (3v^2-u^2-1), 4 u^2 v
\right)$

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.96500ec4c2.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.96500ec4c2.png)

Surface IV. Parametric form: 
$\mathbf{r}(u,v)=\left((u^2 - v^2)\left(1 - \frac{1}{u^2 + v^2}\right) - \ln(u^2 + v^2), 2 u v \left(1 - \frac{1}{u^2 + v^2}\right), 4 u\right)$

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.e2a5391e12.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.e2a5391e12.png)

An example of a kind of an answer I would be happy to get: the surface $\left(y^2+z^2\right)(1-z)=x^2z$ is a *parabolic horn cyclide*; see [mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicHornCyclide.html).

Comment: Up to what equivalence relation? The tags are unclear. 

Comment: From an algebraic geometry point of view: the surfaces I-III are rational surfaces. I.e., they contain an open that is isomorphic with an open in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Several rational surfaces come with a name, but most of them are smooth projective (del Pezzo surfaces, quadric surfaces), whereas your surfaces are singular.

Examples of rational surfaces "come with a name" are cones over rational curves, surfaces swept out by a morphism between two curves. You can check whether your surfaces are of one of these types.

Comment: This question is not quite mathematical: it is asked whether specialists (in algebraic or differential geometry, or variational calculus) could recognize some famous surfaces among given ones.

Comment: Equivalence relation can be stated precisely (Laguerre equivalence) but this seems to be not important because each given surface has already (probably) simplest parametrization among its equivalence class.


Comment: All the image links in this post are broken, but my attempts to fix them were unsuccessful.

Comment: The links seem to be broken...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **Surface I** yet has no name, I would christen it [*Winged Victory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_Victory_of_Samothrace). :-)

          
[image: Surface 1]

Answer (score 3):

I would call Surface I the "Whitney Umbrella"

Comment: To add a reference: [Wikipedia's page on Whitney's Umbrella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_umbrella).

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to check whether your surfaces are equivalent to any
from [this list](http://www1-c703.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/project/bildergalerie/gallery.html).